# Appserv mcrypt with windows 7

Tags: php, mcrypt

i have already uncomment in php.ini
i have already put the libmcrypt.dll in system32/
i have already check the appserv/php5/ext/ contains php_mcrypt.dll
i have already restart PC many time
and im using PC

but still cant load it

any solution??

Answer (score 3):

1. Open your php.ini file, which is `C:\Windows\php.ini`, and change `;extension=php_mcrypt.dll` to `extension=php_mcrypt.dll` (just removing the `;` from the beginning of the line).
2. Copy the file `C:\AppServ\php5\libmcrypt.dll` to folder `C:\AppServ\Apache2.2`.
3. Restart Apache.

Answer (score 1):

try to put your libmcrypt.dll at C:/windows/ not system32/

Comment: This the answer that actually works - especially if you are using cli

Answer (score 1):

No need to copy those `system32` or `windows` folders. Besides enable the extension in `php.ini`, you only need to copy `{Your-PHP-Root}\libmcrypt.dll` to `{Your-Apache-Root}\bin`, then restart apache, the problem should be solved.